# "The syntax of the command is incorrect" issues

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am having problems with my batch file. I am trying to use BGInfo the display the users IP address on their desktop. My code is:

```
If Not Exist "C:\Users\%username%\Information"
(
    copy "\\heartbeat\shared\Information\bginfo.exe" "C:\Users\%username%\bginfo.exe"    
    copy "\\heartbeat\shared\Information\display.bgi" "C:\Users\%username%\display.bgi"
)
C:\Users\%username%\bginfo.exe "C:\Users\%username%\display.bgi" /timer:0
```

I am being told that the syntax is incorrect of the IF statement. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Move the parentheses up: `If Not Exist "C:\Users\%username%\Information" (`

Comment: And you should use `%userprofile%` instead of `C:\Users\%username%` as the user's profile directory can be on a different drive than drive `C:` and can be also in a different directory than `Users`.  __USERPROFILE__ is a predefined environment variable with path to the user's home directory, see [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows). And in the last line of your code use `"%userprofile%\bginfo.exe"` with surrounding double quotes as user account name in path could also contain a space character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Not Exist "%UserProfile%\Information\" MD "%UserProfile%\Information"
If Not Exist "%UserProfile%\Information\bginfo.exe" (
    Copy "\\heartbeat\shared\Information\bginfo.exe" "%UserProfile%\Information")
If Not Exist "%UserProfile%\Information\display.bgi" (
    Copy "\\heartbeat\shared\Information\display.bgi" "%UserProfile%\Information")
Start "" /D"%UserProfile%\Information" bginfo.exe display.bgi /timer:0 /nocliprompt /silent
```